# Android error while retrieving information from server 'RPC:s-5:AEC-0' in Google Play?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have been getting the following error on a mid-Android device.

> Error retrieving information from server rpc:s-5:aec-0` .

It pops up when I try to download my in-app purchase product from the [Play store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play).

I did coding from the tutorial *[Simple InApp Billing / Payment](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment/)* and updated my [APK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) file in Google Play, but it not published. Is it compulsory to publish an app on Google Play?

I installed the same APK file in a device which I have kept in Google Play. Now I am getting this error. What is the problem and how do I to solve it?

Comment: You have to wait 1-2 hours for Google Play servers to register your in-app items and then you can begin the buying process.

Comment: for those who googled for [RPC:S-5:AEC-0] error: you don't need to remove your account (as top answers suggest). Look for other answers below: clearing cache/data for "Google Services Framework" and "Google Play Store" was sufficient for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've been having this problem too and I'm not sure why. Some people suggest removing your Google account and re-adding it and/or deleting the Play Store cache. I'm looking for more solutions, but it happens for all apps free, paid, whatever.

EDIT: just found this http://www.droid-life.com/2012/11/14/after-4-2-update-is-your-nexus-7-having-troubles-updating-apps-in-google-play/

Comment: ... and what if Android (2.3.5) refuses to delete your account and says that the only way to do so is to perform a factory reset?

Answer (score 11):

To fix this issue you need to remove your Google account, then add it again. To do this follow these instructions:

http://support.google.com/android/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1663649

(Or just find the account under Settings > Personal > Accounts and Sync > Click the Google Account > Click Menu button > Click Remove Account > Confirm deletion.)

Comment: Even if this worked for a user, as developers we do not want our users to have to do this...

Comment: ... and what if Android (2.3.5) refuses to delete your account and says that the only way to do so is to perform a factory reset? Also, the link is dead.

Answer (score 9):

I tried everything form everywhere. Nothing worked until I did this.
Following the steps below.

`RPC:AEC:0` error is known as CPU/RAM/Device/Identity failure.

Only possible way you can follow to get rid off this error is,

Go to <kbd>settings</kbd> → <kbd>application</kbd> → <kbd>Play Store</kbd> → <kbd>Clear Data</kbd> & <kbd>Clear Cache</kbd>.

Go to <kbd>accounts</kbd> → <kbd>Google</kbd> → <kbd>Remove account</kbd>.

Reboot device.

Again <kbd>Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Account</kbd> → <kbd>Google</kbd> → <kbd>Log In</kbd>.

Comment: The problem still exists after following these steps :(

Comment: ... and what if Android (2.3.5) refuses to delete your account and says that the only way to do so is to perform a factory reset?

Answer (score 4):

I solved it this way:

- Settings ->
- Apps ->
- All Apps ->
- Google Play Store ->
- Delete Cache ->
- Force Stop ->
- Google Services Framework ->
- Delete Data ->
- Force Stop

Then **restart** your device. Now enjoy...

It's 100% working.

Answer (score 4):

I was having trouble with this issue and had tried everything that everyone had posted with no success.  I finally was able to contact Google and got someone on the phone.  With their help I had it fixed in minutes.  Here's what worked for me...

1. Settings --> Applicaitons --> Manage Applications --> All
2. Select Download Manager; clear data; clear cache; go back
3. Select Google Play Store; clear data; clear cache; go back
4. Select Google Services Framework; clear data; clear cache; go back
5. Turn off phone
6. Turn on phone

It worked for me.  Hope this helps someone.  Also, be aware they did say that it could take a few minutes for it to work -- possibly up to 30 minutes after restarting the phone.  I did notice when restarting the phone that the Google Play Store had to update itself first.  But now it is resolved.  Finally!

Answer (score 2):

Go to "app manager", then go to "all", then click on "Google Services Framework" and then "Clear Data". Reboot and it is done.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem (RPC:S-5:AEC-0):

1. Go to settings
2. Go to backup and reset
3. Go down to recovery mode
4. Reboot the system

This seemed to fix the problem for my tab. Now I can use Google Play store and download any app I want.

Comment: Even if this worked for a user, as developers we do not want our users to have to do this...

Answer (score 2):

1. Enter into SETTING
2. Choose"Apps" & All
3. Select Google Services Framework
4. Clear data
5. Force stop
6. Go to Apps and download without error

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to remove an account: I switched Google Play to a second Google account, installed an update, and switched back to my original account.

Though apparently, it's sufficient to just switch to a second Google Account, and switch back to the original account, no need to install an update.

Comment: after hours of banging my head against the wall this suggestion finally worked.  i tried everything else in the thread.  how is it possible that android is the most popular mobile os? it is so buggy!  Thank you for posting this, its saved me from destroying my phone.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many things (even those included in this post) but nothing worked.  I decided to clear the data for the google account manager since so many mentioned to delete the account and recreate the account.  It worked for my Nexus 7 (Android 4.2.2).  Received 17 updates :-).

Go to Settings → Apps → ALL → Google Account Manager → Clear Data.

Reboot device.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple... I'm sure that you all have a notebook or a PC at your home. So go to `http://www.google.com/wallet/`, sign in with your Google account and go to "Payment methods" and then to "Add Card or Account".

When you add the payment method, it's done! You will be able to buy your apps.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue use the method on http://matthill.eu/android/google-play-error-rpcs5aec0/

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error while using in-app-purchase in android. My mistake is I used wrong purchase id while instantiating the purchases.

```
public static final String PRODUCT_ID_ASTRO_Match = "android.test.product";//wrong id not in play store dev console
```

Replaced it with:

```
public static final String PRODUCT_ID_ASTRO_Match = "android.test.purchased";
```

and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

I've finally solved this problem. It was driving me nuts. From a PC, go to [Google Play](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play). In my case I had conflicting email accounts and had to create a new email account. Then go to your phone settings. Go to accounts and then Google. Remove your existing email there and add the new one.

The phone will then synchronise and then everything works again. You can then update and download apps; which is what I couldn't do before because of this problem.